# Why it should be "a key to being successful", instead of "a key to be successful"

Tags: to-infinitive

After I googled a lot, I beleive that the following sentence should be correct:

> Confidence can be seen as a key to **being** successful.

However, I still do not understand why this is incorrect:

> Confidence can be seen as a key to **be** successful

Comment: There's a distinct difference between the two. "Being" implies continuity, where "be" implies that it is something which you can arrive at and then end. So a key to _be_ successful would bring you to success, where a key to _being_ successful would maintain your successful status.

Comment: We generally would use: is seen as the key to success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the prepostion "to" followed by a particple/gerund "being successful".

The usual expression is "a key to " for example "A key to the front door" or "A key to the suitcase".  Figuratively you can use key as "A key to a good job".  In all these example the idiom uses the prepostion "to".

The object of prepositions can be a noun  "a key to the door" or a gerund "A key to being successful".

Don't confuse this with "to" as a particle in the infinitive. The infinitive expression is possible, but less common, and would have something of the meaning of "a key in order to be successful", which isn't quite the intended meaning here.

Answer (score 1):

I think the source of the confusion is that "key" can be an adjective, meaning "crucial". So for example you can say "confidence is key" or "several key decision-makers were involved". The phrase "confidence is key" is a common expression whereas "confidence is a key" sounds like an awkward newly-coined metaphor.

The other part of the question is the conjugation of "be successful". When you have "key" being used as an adjective like this, "key to X" requires X to be a noun phrase. Using an infinitive doesn't satisfy this requirement. That's why it should be "key to being successful".

In fact, even if you were to say "a key to", which again, sounds awkward, the correct way to say it would be "a key to being successful" or even "a key to success".